# Domain Resolution Failing - Failed To Open Stream - GettAddrInfo Failed: Name Or Service Not Known

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, debian

I woke up today and suddenly my server can no longer resolve any domains.

Domain resolution has always been extremely slow for my server, now it doesn't even work at all:

```
root@server:~# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search ovh.net
```

Here is a sample of the error log.

```
file_get_contents(http://APIOnly.com/pingipv4.php?ip=http://APIOnly.com/pingipv4.php?ip=8.8.8.8): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
```

Here is my nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Just to check - your file should be called `/etc/resolv.conf` (no 'e' in 'resolv') - is this correct on your system?

Comment: Also, it seems that you've signed up multiple times - the user you have used to edit the post is not the same user that you used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `resolv.conf` file has too many octets for your primary DNS server. It should look like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search ovh.net
```